# Why would my data be available at build time but not at render time?

Tags: jsp, jsf, components, jstl, facelets

I have read many of the answers and pages but I cannot seem to find a situation similar to my own (I am guessing then, that my mistake is just a bone-head one).

I am simply trying to print out a list of items. c:forEach works... but ui:repeat does not (nor do any of my primefaces datagrids/tables).

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <ui:composition template="/templates/pageLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="windowTitle">Manage my Worklists</ui:define>
        <ui:define name="pageContent">

            <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="puradmin-style.css"  />

            <h:form id="manage-worklist" prependId="false">
                <br/>
                <c:forEach items="#{manageWorklistBean.givenAccessList}" var="friend">
                    <h:outputText value="* #{friend.receivingUser.name}" />
                    <br/>
                </c:forEach>
                <br/>
                <ui:repeat value="#{manageWorklistBean.givenAccessList}" var="friend">
                    <h:outputText value="* #{friend.receivingUser.name}" />
                    <br/>
                </ui:repeat>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

And here is my output:

* Friend One 
* Friend Two 
* Friend Three 
* 
* 
*

Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: So, given the three empty `*` lines, it thus properly iterates, but each `#{friend.receivingUser.name}` prints nothing, right? What appserver impl/version? What JSF impl/version? What if you print `#{friend}` instead of `#{friend.receivingUser.name}`? What if you give `<ui:repeat>` a different `var` name than the `<c:forEach>` one, e.g. `var="_friend"` with `#{_friend}`? I can't reproduce your problem with Mojarra 2.1.12 on Tomcat 7.0.27, provided that backing bean and model code is written properly according standard idioms.

Comment: Thank you so much! These were great suggestions. I was able to solve my problem in seconds. In my full page.. I have the var="friend" in two different components (a little lazy I know). I'm using Mojarra 2.1.6 and Glassfish 3.1.2

Comment: You're welcome. I already guessed something like that, but the code provided so far would impossibly cause that (surely your `var="friend"` would be elsewhere in another JSF iterating component). I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the three empty `*` lines, the iteration thus works flawlessly, but each item as represented by the `var` attribute couldn't be resolved for some reason. One of the possible causes is a naming conflict in the `var` attribute in the EL scope during view render time, most likely caused by using another JSF iterating component in the same view which also uses the same `var` attribute name. Giving it a different and unique name should fix the problem, as confirmed in the comments of the question.