# Some data of JSF2 Bean from database not available at render time

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I am running into a weird problem when rendering JSF2 (Facelet) pages. It is the usual page that receives an `id` via `GET` and displays the object. The object has a List<> inside, and the problem is that sometimes that list prints nothing and sometimes I refresh and prints the list partially (all the elements but not all the information about them). It also happens with other object's attributes (some dates). I have checked with some logging and the information is obtained correctly from the DB and the object `set`s the information.

I am quite sure that this is because `preRenderView` is done just before the render, so the bean is by chance not available when I use `c:if` or `c:each`. For the second case, perhaps `ui:repeat` [would solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)?.

My questions are:

1. How can I fix this?
2. Is there a way in Facelets, to render f.ex. a
   `<section>` or `<time>` (as in my `document.xhtml` below) and don't
   print the empty tag if rendered computes to false? I know I can use
   `c:if`, but rendered is recommended in Facelets.
3. Has the DB Javabean `Document` to be `Named` as well (besides DocumentController)?

Also, please, if there is a better way to do what I am doing (a page that receives an `id` via `GET` and displays the object), please advise. I am totally new to JSF.

Btw, I have discarded it is due to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179672/why-would-my-data-be-available-at-build-time-but-not-at-render-time).

**DocumentController.java**

```
@Named(value = "DocumentController")
@SessionScoped
public class DocumentController implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private Document document;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the Document
     */
    public Document getDocument() {
        return document;
    }

    /**
     * @param Document the Document to set
     */
    public void setDocument(Document document) {
        this.document = document;
    }


    public void load() {
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if (ctx.isValidationFailed()) {
            ctx.getApplication().getNavigationHandler()
                    .handleNavigation(ctx, "#{DocumentController.load}", "invalid");
            return;
        }

        try (DataStore dst = new DataStore()) {
            dst.connect();
            document = dst.getDocument(id);

        } catch (NoData | ConnectionError | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ctx.getApplication().getNavigationHandler()
                    .handleNavigation(ctx, "#{DocumentController.load}", "invalid");
        }
    }

}
```

**document.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:utils="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/utils"
                template="template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{documentController.id}" required="true"/>
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{documentController.load}"/>
        </f:metadata>
...
        <section rendered="#{not empty documentController.document.participants}">
            <utils:participants
                participants="#{documentController.document.participants}
                cid="example"/>
....
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**participants.xhtml**

```
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
              xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
              xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
              xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
              xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="participants" type="java.util.List" required="true"/>
        <cc:attribute name="cid" type="String" required="true"/>
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <table>
...
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="#{cc.attrs.participants}" var="participant">
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">#{participant.name}</a></td>
                        <td>#{participant.lastName}</td>
                        <td>#{participant.role(cc.attrs.cid)}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

Comment: It seems what you want to do is use a `h:dataTable` in your composite component instead of building a table yourself. Have a look at the component. Also, for your second question, as they are standard HTML tags, you could wrap then in a `ui:fragment`, which has the `rendered` attribute too and renders no additional HTML code.

Comment: On some elements, I would prefer to use my own HTML5 instead of depending on h:XXX. Also, this would not solve the problem since as I said, it happens with my <time> element too. The second solution looks OK if there is no other option... I dislike it because it looks like the old verbatim overbloat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. How can I fix this?**

As I suspected, this had something to do with `preRenderView`. Clues to find this out were that the logs showed the bean having the data, and that if I used `SessionScoped`, on my refresh the data appeared miraculously, but never appeared with a `RequestScoped` no matter how many times I refreshed - meaning that the data was indeed inside the bean, but could not be displayed at the first time. I fixed it by changing:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{documentController.load}"/>
```

to

```
<f:viewAction action="#{projectController.load}" />
```

See also: [When to use f:viewAction / preRenderView versus PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-fviewaction-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct)

I don't have an answer for (2), (3), or the best practice for what I am trying to do, but at least I wanted to write the main problem solution, in case someone needs it.

**2.** Apparently there is none, at least in the current JSF version. This can be done but it is not ideal:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="...">
```

**3.** Nop